# How to get a Brush from a RGB Code?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

How can I get a `Brush` to set a Background of e.g. a `Grid` from a RGB Code.

I hace the RGB Code as a `int`:

```
R = 12
B = 0
G = 255
```

I need to know how to convert it into a `Brush`

Comment: But this wahts to have bytes as a input

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)R, (byte)G, (byte)B));
myGrid.Background = brush;
```

Comment: You beat me to it :P its `SolidBrush` though

Comment: @Sayse Is it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx

Comment: In WinRT, it is SolidColorBrush. In WinForms, it's SolidBrush. @ChrisSinclair, the link you posted is for WPF. The correct link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx

Comment: The OP mentions WinRT in his tags